# A fun lateral-thinking Chess puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, chess, movies

Which famous movie is suggested by the following chess position (by Trevor Tao)?

[image]

Comment: I badly want this to be the seventh seal for obvious reasons but it definitely isn't xD

Comment: Does it matter who is next to move?

Comment: @Laska I trust you on this, but it's better to include a reference as well. (If it spoils the solution, you can just indicate so like I did [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/33305/7297).)

Comment: https://m.facebook.com/story/graphql_permalink/?graphql_id=UzpfSTEwMDAwMTAzOTI4MzA3MzpWSzo5MDI5NzM5ODcxMjI2OTA%3D

Comment: @laska link busted for me

Comment: @Bohemian. It works for me. Writing in Facebook is like writing in sand anyway. Another way to locate this is to go https://www.facebook.com/groups/544412592978833, Chess Endgame Studies and Conventions, and search on Tao. Any requirement for citation just to put a name in is a bit distracting. I would appreciate if moderators can encourage posters to include the author for compositions (including endgame studies like this, but not tactical problems). There is no intellectual property for chess problems, but problemists strongly expect to see the composer's name.

Comment: @Laska: That facebook group is privite so isn't any good to anyone. Also, are you suggesting that Trevor Tao created this whole puzzle (including the film reference) or did he just create the chess puzzle part? Because editing his name into brackets is ambiguous

Comment: Aha thanks @musefan. Please join the group. Does this problem even count as published? Trevor created the chess problem. Then he stated that a certain film title (which he specified) might make a nice motto for the problem. I don't think he intended that guessing the film title would be part of the problem. I think the poster should make his extension clear. I could just have said: "OP: please post the composer's name" (which OP probably knows full well), but since I know who the composer is, I posted that. Moderator then kind of requested citation from *me*, and didn't push OP! Amazing.

Comment: @Laska Is there anywhere else this problem has appeared, as many people don't have (nor want) a Facebook account?

Comment: @Laska: I think it was more because you made the edit and therefore made the claim. Which could equally have been an invalid claim. Perhaps you are Tao and are trying to steal others puzzles! :D As you say, there is no IP, so there is no onus on OP to actually credit them. Also, perhaps they didn't know. Even if it is a copy, they could have just found it on another site (also unreferenced).

Comment: @Laska: Also, if you know the answer, please post an answer! This is doing my head it for 2 days now! haha

Comment: @hexomino: i have just posted in facebook to ask whether posting in a private group constitutes "publication". Based on the response, I will probably post this in PDB database where anyone can see it. I had an idea about the solution, but I'm not sure it's right. Rather than posting a solution I know, I wanted to leave it open for someone else maybe to solve :D

Comment: OK having had a chance to look at this thread properly, I totally agree with the chess in Bass' response (and have awarded it +1!) however Trevor's idea of a movie title is different from Bass'. What I can say is that Trevor agreed that the version I proposed 8/8/P7/P4Npp/P6P/P6p/P6p/n1K3k1, is even more a demonstration of the movie title he had in mind

Comment: @Laska: Still no idea... why don't you just post an answer, save us all the pain

Answer (score 16):

This is also (one would hope) not the intended answer, but I'll go with the [garbagious](https://www.imdb.com/event/ev0005190/2018/1?ref_=ttawd_ev_4)

> [Transformers: The Last Knight](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3371366/?ref_=adv_li_tt).

That would be because to my eye white can only win by

> sacrificing the Last Knight in the corner:
>  [image]

after which there are a lot of transformers, as

> white and black [both promote three queens](https://lichess.org/Vw2tUMAo#3), which immediately get exchanged away at H1.
>
> ```
>  [FEN "8/8/P7/P4N1p/P7/7p/P6p/n1K3k1 w - - 0 1"]
>  1.  Ng3   h4
>  2.  Nh1   Kxh1
>  3.  a7    Kg1
>  4.  a8=Q  h1=Q
>  5.  Qxh1+ Kxh1
>  6.  a6    Kg1
>  7.  a7    h2
>  8.  a8=Q  h1=Q
>  9.  Qxh1+ Kxh1
>  10. a5    h3
>  11. a6    h2
>  12. a7    Kg1
>  13. a8=Q  h1=Q
>  14. Qxh1+ Kxh1
> ```

The sequence seems forced: white wins this way, and any deviation from black leads to being down a queen.

After this, the white king will step to b2, confining the black's Last Knight into the corner, and the final pawn is free to march to a8.

If you have a better suggestion for a movie based on the solution to the chess part (and you probably do), please drop a comment.

Comment: I have another probably wrong answer based on this solution: [this musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_(musical)).

Comment: Bass has found the right moves for both sides. If you get the movie I'm thinking of then you'll know it's correct :) I don't wanna give too big a hint though

Comment: I'm thinking *Henry VIII*, based on rot13(ubj znal dhrraf jr qrpncvgngr)...

Comment: For what it's worth, Lichess disagrees that this is a win for white, as the black king can catch up to the last pawn and capture it before or immediately after it promotes, leading to stalemate.  (White king takes black knight, and then you're down to just king v. king)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman how does that work? The king needs 7 moves to reach a8, the pawn needs 5, so even if the king goes first, the pawn is well ahead

Comment: @Bass Just go to the link you provided and follow the suggested moves for both sides.  The King only needs to get to b7 (or b6 if white wastes a move taking the black knight).

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: I am lost with what you are saying too... Can you provide a moveset that forces what you suggest?  I mean obviously it's possible if white "wastes moves", but if white doesn't waste moves I can't see black being able to stop that last queen.

Comment: @musefan Okay, I was just following the moves suggested by that site, the first of which was Kb2, followed by black king just moving diagonally to intercept the advancing pawn.  It apparently doesn't suggest the same moves every time though, which is surprising.  I tried it again a few times, and it made some truly bonkers suggestions.  I think what happened was the pawn didn't use its double-move the first time, which left it one move behind.  I would've assumed that Stockfish was smarter than that, but I guess there's some randomness thrown in?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Yeah I don't know the details of the stockfish logic, but perhaps it was running slow and hadn't applied much depth to the suggested moved yet. I can only speculate. I tried a few times myself but never got anything that was good for black. Anyway, I don't think it matter much for the answer to this puzzle! :D

Answer (score 12):

I think this could be:

> **[Black Hawk Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hawk_Down_(film))** (2001)

As:

> The only difference between the two sides' available pieces is a single pawn - specifically, black has one fewer...
>
>  '[Hock](https://whatis.techtarget.com/feature/Hawk-or-hock)' is a synonym for 'pawn' (as in to deposit a possession with a pawnbroker) and in some (US) accents a soundalike for 'Hawk'...
>
>  Thus black is one pawn down, giving us:
>
>  'Black Pawn Down' → 'Black Hock Down' → '*Black Hawk Down*'!

Comment: Very clever but not my intended answer!

Answer (score 4):

> [One Night with the King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Night_with_the_King)

Because

> Both sides have one knight and one king. The plot of the movie centers around a cadre of young women in bondage (pawns) spending a night with a king (being promoted to queens) after which one queen remains. This assumes that white moves first and the game proceeds as @Bass outlines.

Comment: Certainly seems to fit better than the other guesses... although it still seems tenuous.

Comment: There's also an Argentine movie called Nueva Reinas (nine queens) which would make sense (2 queens to start and then 7 promoted), but the plot doesn't seem like much of a connection.

Comment: And I wouldn't call either of these movies famous in 2021.

Comment: Yeah, I found that film too but couldn't justify it. I also am trying to justify the **famous** part of the questrion, expecting it to be a big film. EDIT: Beat me to it with the famous comment!

Comment: March of the Penguins is famous, but that doesn't relate much (yes, pawns are black or white, but they aren't both and they're monogamous, so ... the multiple queens killing each other thing doesn't work)

Comment: Shame they didn't make a sequel: "March of the albino penguins into royalty". I guess it's not the obvious choice for a title sequel... they will probably go with the more obvious "April of the Penguins"

Answer (score 3):

> [Three Men on a Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Men_on_a_Horse_(film))

Because

> 1.  Ng3   h4
>  2.  Nh1
>
>  And now there are three pawns on the horse.

Answer (score 3):

I already posted this in a comment, but might as well make it an actual guess:

> [*Henry VIII* (2003)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0382737/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (or maybe [*Henry VIII* (1979)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080860/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3), or even [*Henry VIII: Man, Monarch, Monster*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10619810/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) - last one doesn't have a date associated with it, and it's a TV series not a movie, unsure if it was officially released or not.  I'm surprised there aren't more of these, and none were theatrical releases.  Maybe there's some other famous Henry VIII movie that just doesn't have his name in the title?)

Explanation being:

> Henry had 6 queens, most of whom didn't last for very long.  In this sequence, we see 6 pawns promoted to queens and then pretty much immediately captured.  (In reality, 2 of Henry's wives outlived him, but whatever - point is except for the first, none of them were queens for very long.)

Answer (score 3):

These answers have been very entertaining for me, thanks everyone!

Here's my guess:

> **[*Seabiscuit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seabiscuit_(film)) (2003)**

Because:

> *[Seabiscuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seabiscuit) was a horse who beat the 1937 Triple-Crown winner War Admiral, by 4 lengths in a 2-horse special in 1938.* The White Knight on the board is Seabiscuit. The "Triple-Crown winner" is the Black King, who has 3 pawns who can promote to Queens. It takes "4 lengths" (4 moves) until White wins with a Checkmate: 1) Seabiscuit initiates with `Ng3, Nb3+` 2) `axb3, h1Q` 3) `Nxh1, Kxh1` 4) `a7` is Checkmate. In this "2-horse special", Seabiscuit becomes our heroic champion!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

> [Pawn Takes Knight (2012)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2206696/)

Because it looks like that's going to happen in the game, but it's not a definite outcome, and there are more pieces in play and many aren't required to support the idea.

Answer (score 2):

It could be

> [Kingpin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingpin_(1996_film))

Because

> The white king can pin the black knight and take it, 
>  While the black king can force the white knight from its position by fear of pinning
>  The last part is a little sketchy. I haven't played chess in a while. I don't know many terms. :)

Comment: Not sure that is classed as a "pin", as the knight is free to move, regardless of if it will be captured or not. I would be inclined to just say the knight is "trapped", although I am no expert - there may be a more specific term for it.

Comment: @musefan, I agree. I have limited knowledge of chess verbiage. It's a Trap! comes to mind now, though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like time to put this thing to bed once and for all

> The movie is Groundhog Day since this question was asked on 2nd February

And of course

> The moves (already pointed out by several solvers) involve repeated promotions and captures on the h1 square, thus justifying the Groundhog Day theme :)

Comment: Hmh. I think this is the least fitting of the movies suggested here.

Comment: I'd be divorced if this was the climax from 4 days of teasing. Disappointed to say the least  :(

Comment: I'd think a better-fitting chess puzzle for this movie would result in a draw due to repeated board positions.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to milk the fact that 2nd of February was Groundhog Day when I posted this. I was astonished to find there are many reasonable answers. File that under "another 1 of life's disappointments!" :(

Comment: The difference one missing [tag:seasonal] tag makes.. :-)